# ordering a union query, 1st query to be shown 1st then the rest alphabetical

Tags: mysql, sql

so I have this query:

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM table1 WHERE name LIKE '%$search%'".
        "UNION ".
        "SELECT name FROM table1 WHERE name LIKE '%".$pieces[0]." ".$pieces[1]."%'".
        "UNION ".
        "SELECT name FROM table1 WHERE name LIKE '%".$pieces[0]." ".$pieces[2]."%' ORDER BY name";
```

and I want the 1st query's results to be 1st in the list and then the rest to be alphabetical. How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the obvious SQL injection comments

```
$sql = "Select 1 as x, name from table1 where name like '%$search$' ".
       "UNION "
        "SELECT 2 as x, name FROM table1 WHERE name LIKE '%".$pieces[0]." ".$pieces[1]."%' ".
    "UNION ".
    "SELECT 2 as x, name FROM table1 WHERE name LIKE '%".$pieces[0]." ".$pieces[2]."%' ".
    " ORDER BY x, name";
```

This will order first query first then next 2 combined alphabetically

if you want all three in order change the 2 to a 3 in the third query.